# Batch wise loading the data from Source to Salesforce

Tags: oracle, salesforce, informatica-powercenter

My Source Oracle is having 3,50,000 records and my target is Salesforce.
I want to load only 300 records for every Informatica session run.
Can someone give an approach how can i automate to load 3,50,000 records with above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to identify how you will select your 300 records from the whole recordset. It may be a creation date or last update date or the combination of some table columns. Once you identify then create a parameter file that has the number of records you want to load in each run. In Mapping, assign the parameter file variable to the Mapping variable and in the source qualifier transformation use source query override option to write your query based on the key identifier and the variable to pick only 300 records and load them to salesforce target. You can modify the flag of the source records if any using Update Strategy or using the Post SQL method to reduce the number of records to read from the next load onwards.